# jQuery: dynamic image markers based on coordinates from data file

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates, imagemap

I have an image map and a file contain lists of coordinates:

```
var coord_data = {
  "100 100": "2010-_MG_0419.jpg"
  "110 110": "2010-_MG_0412.jpg"};
```

I want to put a marker on each of these coordinates on the image map.

Getting some inspiration from @RDeving, I have a version that is working somehow:

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/xliotx/C5WxK/1832/)

But if I change:

```
                $('<span class="marker"/>').css({
                "top": 100,
                "left": 200
            }).appendTo(target);
```

To:

```
                $('<span class="marker"/>').css({
                "top": coords[0],
                "left": coords[1]
            }).appendTo(target);
```

The css won't work for the location of the marker.

I've searched for a while and in vain.

Any ideas why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the image in a "img" DOM element you could just...

```
// Have some css
img#myimage {
  position: relative;
}
label.icon {
  position: absolute;
}


//Append them dynamically
const $imgTag = $("img#myimage");

coord_data.forEach( data => {
  const coords = data.split(" ");
  $imgTag.append( $("<label>").addClass("icon").css({
    'top': coords[0],
    'left': coords[1]
  }) );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm a little new to jQuery, but my browser said "coord_data.forEach" is not a function...

Comment: maybe you shall use a for ... loop to achieve the same result

Comment: I made the code no error, but still a little confused about the logic. Do I need to add something to the html? otherwise how to link the svg icon into the webpage?

Comment: the snipet i wrote only appends a new label on the img element for each entry in the array and allocate them in said x,y coords, is just a code-pseudocode example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got the solution.
If the value is a "string" type, I also need to add "px".
But if the value is a "integer" type, no "px" is needed.

So this would work:

```
$('<span class="marker"/>').css({
    "top": coords[0]+"px",
    "left": coords[1]+"px"
    }).appendTo(target);
```

Or

```
"top": parseInt(coords[0]),
```